# How do I install all dependencies automatically?

Tags: package-management, wine, packages

For example, I have "winehq-devel_4.12.1_buster_amd64", which requires "wine", which requires "wine-development", and so on.
(I mean .deb files here, being installed by Package Manager)

How do I install all tree/stack of dependencies?

The same thing using the command line to install apps? (using apt-get ...)

Note: I have Deepin OS 15.10.2, if needed.

Also, how to do that for latest releases of software (from developer)?

For now I'm trying to install Wine, and here specifically the [wine-devel-0386 dependency](https://pastebin.com/KBAjqBxY). Is there a way to solve this (and similar situations) automatically?

Comment: APT solves dependencies but apparently you're trying to install something that has dependencies that can't be installed.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still kind of a newbie & I'm on a Unix OS, so good chance I could be way off.... But anyway...

Have you read this wiki page? They mention resolving dependency conflicts r/t outdated packages or 64 vs 32 bit issues, etc...

[WineHq Wiki](https://wiki.winehq.org/Ubuntu)

> ”If you have previously installed a Wine package from another
>   repository, please remove it and any packages that depend on it (e.g.,
>   wine-mono, wine-gecko, winetricks) before attempting to install the
>   WineHQ packages, as they may cause dependency conflicts.”

Or have you tried using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/)? 
See this blog post below, for info on that. It talks specifically about using HBrew for help w/ Wine install. 
[David Baumgold](https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/wine-mac/)

> ”Homebrew is a package manager that makes installing open source
>   programs much easier. In particular, trying to install a large program
>   like Wine without the help of a package manager would be tremendously
>   difficult. Fortunately, Homebrew itself is simple to install: just
>   open up the Terminal and run this command:”

```
`ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`
```

**Good luck!**